# Creating a loop in a C# botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm designing a bot that queries a database, however I've hit a wall.

```
[LuisIntent("ProjectInfo")]
        public async Task projectInfo(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            PromptDialog.Text(context,AfterPromptMethod,"Please enter your project name", attempts: 100);
        }
        async Task AfterPromptMethod(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> userInput)
        {
            var InputText = await userInput;
            string projectName = InputText.ToString();
            if (projectName!= null)
            {
                TestInfo MI = new TestInfo();
                if (MI.FindProject(projectName) == 0)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"Project Found. What do you want to know ?");
                }
                else
                {
//PromptDialog.Text(context,AfterPromptMethod,"Pleaase check your product name and try again", attempts: 100);
                    await context.PostAsync($"Project Not Found. Check your project name and try again.");

                }
            }
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
```

This is where I'd like to put the loop, projectInfo is called alright, but when it reaches the if statement where project isn't found, it does nothing. I've tried to insert "context.Wait(projectInfo)" but it didn't help. I also tried to use the prompt dialog, if yes it loops back if no it goes to main menu. However I haven't been able to wrap my head around that approach.

Does anyone have any suggestions or better ways of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want to is to go again to the projectInfo method, then just call it :)

I updated your code

```
[LuisIntent("ProjectInfo")]
public async Task projectInfo(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    PromptDialog.Text(context,AfterPromptMethod,"Please enter your project name", attempts: 100);
}

async Task AfterPromptMethod(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> userInput)
{
    var InputText = await userInput;
    string projectName = InputText.ToString();
    if (projectName!= null)
    {
        TestInfo MI = new TestInfo();
        if (MI.FindProject(projectName) == 0)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Project Found. What do you want to know ?");
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Project Not Found. Check your project name and try again.");
            await this.projectInfo(context, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `context.Wait(..)`. When the `PromptDialog` is hit a different dialog is created and that dialog will handle the prompt. But the code execution in this method doesn't just exit there. It continues on to the end of the method and the next thing it hits is the `context.wait(MessageRecieved)`. This line tries to specify that the next message should be handled in the MessageRecieved method. So you have 2 places the next message is expected to go and that can't be.

To solve your problem add a `return;` directly after your PromptDialog. This will make sure the context.wait(..) isn't hit.

Comment: Would the return; jump back to the projectInfo ? or just stop it from reaching the context.Wait

Comment: In projectInfo function just add context.wait(AfterPromptMethod) ;)

Comment: i agree with this statement, it seems viable